# How do I Construct a Simple FM Antenna?

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, reception

I recently bought a cheap stereo amplifier with built in FM receiver from Amazon at the first link below. Testing it out today I found the FM reception to be sub-par. All of my local stations that I can pick up in my car sound fuzzy. The antenna is approximately 14 inches long and is simply a floppy cord. Pictures are at the second link below.

I would like to build a better antenna to get better reception. If I can get reception equal to the reception you find on an OEM economy box car radio, I'd be plenty happy. What is a simple path forward?

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07QKW2WMF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKW2WMF)

[image: Mini Wireless Bluetooth Power Amplifier, ARCHEER 2 x 45W]

Comment: To add a bit of detail to my question, I've been researching this question, and based on the 14 inch length, it seems like the current antenna is an "eight wave" antenna. I do not know whether replacing this with a quarter wave or half wave antenna would work given that the system is built around the existing antenna. I also wonder what the best way to form a connection is.

Comment: Can you provide a photo of how the antenna connects to the radio?

Comment: Does the car have any kind of antenna built in?

Comment: The Amazon link has a picture of the rear panel.  The antenna is a wire that sticks out a hole in the rear panel.

Comment: @rclocher3 thank you.  Bill, "simple" is relative, are you willing to open the box and solder?  Can you post a photo of how the wire is connected inside?

Comment: It appears this device has no provisions for an external antenna.  If you want to fix the antenna, you will have to open it up and modify it.

Comment: Well, I ended up finding a much better receiver at a yard sale, and returning the receiver unit from my post to amazon. The yard sale unit even came with a pair of rabbit ears, so I've got the best radio I could hope for, it picks up about 30 channels with perfect reception now. Compared to ~10 channels with terrible reception. And I don't even have to solder anything!